# Unable to delete video on Sharepoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, library

I'm trying to delete a video file that is saved inside a SharePoint online library and always gives me the error "**You have to delete all the items in this folder before you can delete the folder**". The user has the permissions to do it, also the item is not locked or check out.

I try deleting the file from SharePoint Designer and I can see that the video is actually a folder that has:

1. Video File
2. Folder: "Preview Images"
3. Folder: "Additional Content"

If I delete each folder and file from here. I was able to finally delete the video from the library, but this is not a solution, for all the users.

Has anyone experience something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the default behavior due to the retention policy.

More information check the threads:

[Cannot delete folders with items in them - Bug or Feature?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Cannot-delete-folders-with-items-in-them-Bug-or-Feature/td-p/66314)

[How can we improve compliance or protect your users better in Office 365?](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/289138-office-365-security-compliance/suggestions/19799911-onedrive-for-business-unable-to-perform-delete-fol)

Comment: Indeed, thank you for your answer, there was a retention policy implemented to the site collection and that was causing the problem.